# Где берут информацию сервисы по отслеживание посылок?

Tags: парсер, email

Где track24.ru, гдеПосылка и прочие сервисы по отслеживанию посылок с зарубежных интернет магазинов, берут информацию?

Comment: https://www.pochta.ru/tracking

Comment: [история успеха](http://tisunov.github.io/2017/09/15/how-i-built-awesome-package-tracking-app-with-react-native-in-record-time.html)

Comment: [полезная информация](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Package_tracking)